# Where is the Shadow Orb in the demo world?

Tags: terraria-console

I have the PS vita demo and was wondering where exactly I can find the Shadow Orb.

Comment: Not a dupe. This question is asking where it is, not if it's in the game.

Comment: No, they're not dupes.  But it really should just be followed up with in that question.  The two are extremely related, and a good answer will tell you where it is; you don't need a separate question for that.

Answer (score 2):

In all versions of Terraria the shadow orbs are located at the bottom of the corruption. Use a pickaxe to destroy them. An item will drop from each one, after destroying 3 of them, the Eater of Worlds will appear and a random meteor drop could occur at any time. Assuming all these features are in the demo.

Comment: Reason for down vote?

Comment: You didn't read the entire question. Jsh asks where the location of a specific shadow orb is in the demo world.

Comment: Texenox is right, could you tell me where its at? Thx

Comment: Its a bit hard for someone to give you an exact map when the world is randomly genereated.. this is really as best as youll get for a marker on the map.

Comment: Obviously you do not know what the demo is, the world is always the same every time

Comment: My answer still would not change.... at the bottom of the corruption. Unless it's a crimson map (red corruption) in which case it's a crimson heart. If it's not at the bottom of the corruption, the demo is wrong.

Comment: You don't get it... I am asking where is the corruption?

Comment: Terraria is a game about exploration... so why not search the whole map? You'll find more than just a shadow orb. :D (except the corruption might not be in the demo version... be aware of this.)